# How can I open *.bsr files in ubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, files

I just used an spectrophotometer and the data collected on the software was saved in this BSR file. I took it home, and now that I'm trying to open it, I can't. Someone knows about this files?

I'm currently using Lubuntu 16.04

Comment: Internet searches indicate this maybe a MS Windows file related to Bacula Restore. See if your spectrophotometer software allows you to save data in a more "open" format.

Comment: You could also try using the `file` command to see if the format is recognized by its "file magic" e.g. `file somefile.bsr`

Comment: It prints "data"